# Setting variables to the names of files in batch

Tags: variables, batch-file, detection

So I'm making a little simulator game, and i need the system to recognize the health and stamina that was previously saved onto that account.

For example, if a player exits the game with four health, when they reload their save, their health will still be at 4. I've toyed around with the CMD Prompt and my code for a little bit, and I just can't seem to find a way. Any help?

Thanks.

Comment: See here in a search: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=save+load+game+[batch-file]

Answer (score 0):

Lol try using the >> and < things. They make .txt files that can then be read by the batch file Watch:

```
@echo off
if %health% EQU 10 (
echo 10 >> health.txt
)
if %health% EQU 9 (
echo 9 >> health.txt
)
if %health% EQU 8 (
echo 8 >> health.txt
)
if %health% EQU 7 (
echo 7 >> health.txt
)
if %health% EQU 6 (
echo 6 >> health.txt
)
if %health% EQU 5 (
echo 5 >> health.txt
)
if %health% EQU 4 (
echo 4 >> health.txt
)
if %health% EQU 3 (
echo 3 >> health.txt
)
if %health% EQU 2 (
echo 2 >> health.txt
)
if %health% EQU 1 (
echo 1 >> health.txt
)
```

That will make the batch file store the health in a text file named health.txt. Now it needs to read it. We will do that with set.

```
@echo off
if %health% EQU 10 (
echo 10 >> health.txt
)
if %health% EQU 9 (
echo 9 >> health.txt
)
if %health% EQU 8 (
echo 8 >> health.txt
)
if %health% EQU 7 (
echo 7 >> health.txt
)
if %health% EQU 6 (
echo 6 >> health.txt
)
if %health% EQU 5 (
echo 5 >> health.txt
)
if %health% EQU 4 (
echo 4 >> health.txt
)
if %health% EQU 3 (
echo 3 >> health.txt
)
if %health% EQU 2 (
echo 2 >> health.txt
)
if %health% EQU 1 (
echo 1 >> health.txt
)
set health=>health.txt
```

Basicly what this does is make a file health.txt and then reads and and names it as a variable %health%. (assuming that %health% is what you are using to store the person's health.
I could help you a lot more if you gave more the code. I would understand better.
In a nutshell, echo >> health.txt makes health.txt, and set health=

Comment: you should think over your second part (reading the value from file). Also, if %health% rises during gameplay, it could reach a maximum of several thousands. This would mean a **lot** of code this way... (lol)

Comment: I know what you're trying to do, but I need a little bit more compact code than that.

Answer (score 0):

The easy way is to reserve a prefix for all of the variables you want to save. For example, use `$` as a prefix for all variables-to-save.

Now: suppose you have the player's name in some obscure variable such as say, `playername`.

set some random values for the sake of example:

```
set /a $health=7
set /a $stamina=5
set "$somethingelseofinterest=+1 Greatsword of dragon-slaying"
set "playername=Fred"
```

Then to save the required settings, all you need is

```
set $ >"%playername%.game"
```

which will save all of the `$` variables to a file called "Fred.game"

To reload the variables of interest,

```
if exist "%playername%.game" (
 for /f "delims=" %%a in ('type "%playername%.game" ') do set %%a
) else (
 rem in here you could set defaults for a new player
)
```